# How to render svg in backend and save to local using in node js using d3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, jsdom

When I'm trying to draw a pie chart using d3js and the error  d3.entries is not a function but I'm in d3js version 6.5.0. Any help will be appreciated.

And also please let know any other options are there to generate a svg file using node js and add it to a pdf directly .

```
const d3 = require("d3");
const fs = require("fs");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

// init d3 - https://gist.github.com/tomgp/c99a699587b5c5465228
const dom = new JSDOM(
  `<!DOCTYPE html><body><div id="my_dataviz"></div></body>`,
  { pretendToBeVisual: true }
);

let body = d3.select(dom.window.document.querySelector("#my_dataviz"));

// D3JS CODE * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

let width = 400;
let height = 400;
let marin = 60;
let radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - marin;

var svg = body.append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

var data = { MacOS: 29, ios: 20, Windows: 30, Linux: 8, Android: 12 };

// set the color scale
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["MacOS", "ios", "Windows", "Linux", "Android"])
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);

var pie = d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value((data) => data.value);
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));

svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("id", "rect1")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 80)
  .attr("height", 80)
  .style("fill", "green");
// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

console.log(body.html());
```

The error is happening at:

```
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))
```

> TypeError: d3.entries is not a function

package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "d3_charts",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "type": "module",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/SubhamSubhasisPatra/d3.git"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/SubhamSubhasisPatra/d3/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/SubhamSubhasisPatra/d3#readme",
      "dependencies": {
        "d3": "^6.5.0",
        "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
        "d3-node": "^2.2.3",
        "pdfkit": "^0.12.3"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In d3.js v6, `d3.entries` is replaced by `Object.entries`, as explained in the [d3 6.0 migration guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide).

In your case, the following modification should solve the problem:

```
var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data));
```

> And also please let know any other options are there to generate a svg file using node js

To generate charts server side using d3, it might be easier to use [`d3-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-node).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. if I'm using d3 then I have to add an extension .cjs instead of .js . is there any way to use the .js extension as well as use require('d3') . Please let me know .

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to do some research regarding file extensions, and post a separate question in case you do not find  an answer. You may mark the answer above as 'accepted' since it solved the original problem :)